# Error when running OpenCl program visual studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, opencl

I am using visual studio 2010 and just started to learn opencl

Now my problem: when i run any program written in opencl this message appears:

```
is not recognized as internal or external command,
operable program or patch file.
```

what is the solution for this problem ?

This is a code written in opencl and c++ .. this program should sum two arrays and print the results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.hpp>

int main(){
//get all platforms (drivers)
std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);
if(all_platforms.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No platforms found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[0];
std::cout << "Using platform: "<<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<"\n";

//get default device of the default platform
std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, &all_devices);
if(all_devices.size()==0){
    std::cout<<" No devices found. Check OpenCL installation!\n";
    exit(1);
}
cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";


cl::Context context({default_device});

cl::Program::Sources sources;

// kernel calculates for each element C=A+B
std::string kernel_code=
        "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){       "
        "       C[get_global_id(0)]=A[get_global_id(0)]+B[get_global_id(0)];                 "
        "   }                                                                               ";
sources.push_back({kernel_code.c_str(),kernel_code.length()});

cl::Program program(context,sources);
if(program.build({default_device})!=CL_SUCCESS){
    std::cout<<" Error building: "<<program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(default_device)<<"\n";
    exit(1);
}


// create buffers on the device
cl::Buffer buffer_A(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_B(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);
cl::Buffer buffer_C(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,sizeof(int)*10);

int A[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
int B[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0};

//create queue to which we will push commands for the device.
cl::CommandQueue queue(context,default_device);

//write arrays A and B to the device
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_A,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,A);
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_B,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,B);


//run the kernel
cl::KernelFunctor simple_add(cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add"),queue,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
simple_add(buffer_A,buffer_B,buffer_C);

//alternative way to run the kernel
/*cl::Kernel kernel_add=cl::Kernel(program,"simple_add");
kernel_add.setArg(0,buffer_A);
kernel_add.setArg(1,buffer_B);
kernel_add.setArg(2,buffer_C);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel_add,cl::NullRange,cl::NDRange(10),cl::NullRange);
queue.finish();*/

int C[10];
//read result C from the device to array C
queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_C,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(int)*10,C);

std::cout<<" result: \n";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    std::cout<<C[i]<<" ";
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: I dare say we don't have enough information to answer your question. This message is a little bit vague. In what circumstances does it occurs? Also, what do you mean by "a program written in OpenCL"?

Comment: @HenriqueJung post edited, please check.

Comment: Is it only for OCL apps or for any app? Because it looks that the executable you generated is not understand by the OS.

Comment: It looks like something is not configured properly on your project solution, I don't think there's anything to do with code itself. You haven't manage to _compile_ the code. Try to paste this code on a new solution from VS, or even using another IDE/Compiler. Also you might have forgotten the first word of your message, _what_ is not recognized?